# Live wallpaper installation location

Tags: samsung, live-wallpaper

I've got Samsung A3 on Android 5.0.2 Lollipop and some time ago I installed a few live wallpapers, but they are not showing in installed apps so I can't uninstall them.

With the WiFi Transfer app, I can look through the whole file system, but I can't locate them to manually delete it.

Where are live wallpapers being kept in the system?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if TouchWiz even support live wallpaper.

Comment: Do you not see the app's entry under Settings -> Apps -> All apps or the equivalent location in your device?

Answer (score 1):

Live wallpapers can be uninstalled like normal apps.

1. Open "Settings"
2. Choose "Apps"
3. Find the live wallpaper
4. Uninstall

I you installed the wallpapers from the Play Store then you can remove it from the Play Store app.

Comment: Nearly all of them can but not these two: Bubbles and Phase Beam, something must have went wrong and they are not visible in Apps. So if anyone knows where to manually find the files and delete them. Please let me know.

Comment: Is the apk file for the wallpaper present under the /system/app/ directory?

Comment: No, I have checked this location already. Any other possible places to look?

Comment: How do you know that the wallpapers are installed? Can you still set them?

Comment: Yes they are available in wallpaper menu and I can use them

Comment: @MannyCalavera AFAIK, Bubbles and Phase Beam are part of [the default/stock/system live wallpapers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3yxt.jpg) on older Android (at least I remember Bubbles, Holo Spiral, Nexus, and Phase Beam). Though, I'm not sure where they are stored since I have never checked them back then.